# Bounding the second moment of a stochastic process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Consider the stochastic process
$$
\theta_{t+1} = \arctan\left( \frac{\lambda_2 \sin \theta_t + \sigma w_t}{\lambda_1\cos \theta_t + \sigma v_t} \right),
$$
where $v_t, w_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ are i.i.d. and $\sigma > 0$ and $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 > 0$ are known parameters. I would like to:

- Prove that $\{\theta_t\}$ is convergent in some sense as $t\to\infty$.
- Find an upper bound on the steady-state variance: $\lim_{t\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[\theta_t^2] \leq M(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\sigma)$.

When $\sigma$ is small compared to $\lambda_1$ and $\theta_t \approx 0$, the dynamics are approximately linear: $\theta_{t+1} \approx \tfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1} \theta_t + \tfrac{\sigma}{\lambda_1} w_t$, so at least in this case, we can expect a steady-state distribution that is approximately normal. Based on a few numerical simulations, it appears that when $\sigma$ is larger, $\{\theta_t\}$ still converges to a steady-state distribution, but it looks more Cauchy-like instead of Gaussian.

Comment: A couple brief comments:1)  I did a quick simulation at work (always unreliable) with $\lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 - .5$ and got a pretty clearly bimodal distribution. 2) arctan is bounded, so it can't be Cauchy.  Might you have meant arctan theta ?  3)  the process is pretty clearly a positive recurrent markov chain, so convergence in distribution should not be tough to prove.

Comment: You are right that my Cauchy comment made no sense --- I was thinking about something else. When I simulate, I find that when $\sigma$ is small, $\theta_t$ looks approximately normal and concentrated around $\theta_t=0$. When $\sigma$ is larger, it tends to a uniform distribution on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. I'm not getting anything bimodal.

Comment: @mike did you perhaps use the same noise realization for the numerator and denominator? It is important that $w_t$ and $v_t$ be uncorrelated. When I use $w_t=v_t$ I do indeed get a bimodal distribution.

Comment: There was a problem with the simulation.   I can explain large $\sigma$, if the normal terms are large enough so that you can ignore the trig terms, the you have arctan(U/V), and the ratio of 2 normal is Cauchy, and arctan of a Cauchy uniform.